# Exiting from a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

Here is a brief description about what am trying to do:

I have 2 buttons : `Button_Auto` that starts the `backgroundWorker_Auto` and `Button_Manual` which stops(should stop) the running `backgroundWorker_Auto` and starts another one, `backgroundWorker_Manual`. Basically, the buttons should allow the user to switch between the 2 modes of operation in my application. Auto & Manual

```
        private Button_Auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (!backgroundWorker_Auto.IsBusy)
                 backgroundWorker_Auto.RunWorkerAsync();
        }      


        private Button_Manual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //some code to stop backgroundWorker_Auto..

             if (!backgroundWorker_Manual.IsBusy)
                 backgroundWorker_Manual.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

The `backgroundWorker_Auto` is simply a TCP client connected to a server, receiving data from API calls made to server from another application.

I have seen lot of solution to cancel background worker with iterators, where it checks the `CancellationPending` property on each iteration. However, in my below code , the `backgroundworker` simply waits for data from TCP server.

```
        public static TcpClient client;

        private void backgroundWorker_Auto_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {              
                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    
                    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);  //CODE WAITS HERE!!
                    String responseData = String.Empty;
                    responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
                    switch (responseData)
                          {
                            case "1":
                            //Do something;
                            break;
                                        
                            case "2":
                            //Do some other thing;
                            break;
                          }
                }
             }

            catch (Exception ex)
             {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
             }                                                                                        
        }
```

The issue is that when the `backgroundWorker_Auto` is started, it waits at the `int bytesRead` line to receive data from server. Once received, it executes the below functions and goes back to the same listening state as above.  So, even if I trigger `CancelAsync` from my `Button_Manual` and change the while loop condition to `backgroundWorker_Auto.CancellationPending`, that won't be checked unless a data is received by the client.

And since `backgroundWorker_Auto` is not stopped, I won't be able to start it again ie, switching between Auto and Manual is not possible.

How can I check for `CancellationPending` condition in this scenario or stop the `backgroundWorker_Auto` properly ?

Comment: Using `ReadAsync` allows you to use a cancellation token to abort the read operation; the synchronous version has no nice way of doing that. You'd have to replace the background worker with an async method, but that isn't too complicated nowadays.

Comment: *Don't* use a BGW in the first place. That class is obsolete, fully replaced by async/await, Task.Run and `IProgress` 10 years ago. In this case both TcpClient and NetworkStream offer asynchronous methods. You could replace all this complex code with a single method that used what you put inside `DoWork` and `Stream.ReadAsync` instead of `Read` etc

Comment: `client.Close();` gets the job done, call it from the button's Click event.  Reconnect it again afterwards, that belongs in the worker anyway.  try/except and the exception reporting is wrong, belongs in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, don't report ObjectDisposedException.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a BackgroundWorker to begin with. That class is obsolete and was fully replaced by `async/await`, `Task.Run` and `IProgress<T>` almost 10 years ago. There are a lot of things that are trivial to do with `async/await` that are very difficult with BGW. That includes cancellation and combining multiple asynchronous operations.

In this case it looks like the BGW can be replaced by a single async method that does what `DoWork` does :

```
async Task ListenAuto(TcpClient client,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    try
        {              
            using var nwStream = client.GetStream();
            var bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            while (client.Connected && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                int bytesRead = await nwStream.ReadAsync(bytesToRead, 0, 
                                         client.ReceiveBufferSize,token);  //Not blocking
                var responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
                switch (responseData)
                      {
                        case "1":
                        await Task.Run(()=>DoSomething1());
                        
                        break;
                                    
                        case "2":
                        await Task.Run(()=>DoSomething2());
                        break;
                      }
            }
         }
         catch(OperationCanceledException)
         {
             //Cancelled, no need to show anything
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
         }     
}
```

This can be improved and simplified:

1. Create the TcpClient in the worker method itself, so it can be safely disposed
2. Use a StreamReader instead of manually decoding bytes.
3. Only read the expected characters, or have a way to handle multiple messages. If the server sent 2 or three consecutive numbers, eg 1, 3, 5, the current code would read them as `135`.

As someone said recently: `Almost all Sockets problems are framing problems`.

In this case, I'll assume each character is a separate message. The code could be reduced to:

```
async Task ListenAuto(IPAddress address,int port,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    try
        {        
            using var client=new TcpClient(endpoint);
            await client.ConnedtAsync(address,port,token);

            using var nwStream = client.GetStream();
            using var reader=new StreamReader(nwStream,Encoding.ASCII);

            var chars = new char[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            while (client.Connected && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                int charsRead = await reader.ReadAsync(chars, 0,chars.Length,token);  //Not blocking
                for(int i=0;i<charsRead;i++)
                {
                    switch (chars[i])
                    {
                     ...
                    }
                 } 
            }
         }
         catch(OperationCanceledException)
         {
             //Cancelled, no need to show anything
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
         }     
}
```

[CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token?view=net-5.0) instances are provided by the [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0) class. This class can only be used to cancel once, which means you need to create a new one each time :

```
    CancellationTokenSource _autoCancel;
    CancellationTokenSource _manualCancel;

    private async void Button_Auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Just in case it's null
        _manualCancel?.Cancel();

        _autoCancel=new CancellationTokenSource();
        await ListenAuto(server,port,_autoCancel.Token);
    }   

    private async void Button_Manual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Just in case it's null
        _autoCancel?.Cancel();

        _manualCancel=new CancellationTokenSource();
        await ListenManual(server,port,_manualCancel.Token);
    }
```

**Separate Listening from Processing**

Another improvement is to *separate* the polling and processing code, especially if processing is the same for both cases. Instead of both listening and processing, `ListenAuto` and `ListenManual` will only check for messages and post them to a worker that processes them asynchronously. There are several ways to implement such a worker.

- Using an ActionBlock in both .NET Core and .NET Framework
- Using a Channel in both
- Using `IAsyncEnumerable` in .NET Core 3 and later

Let's say the worker is an ActionBlock:

```
ActionBlock _block=new ActionBlock(msg=>ProcessMsg(msg));

async Task ProcessMsg(char msg)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case '1':
        ...
    }
}
```

An `ActionBlock` uses one or more tasks (1 by default) to process all messages posted to its input buffer in sequence. By default there's no limit to how many items can be buffered.

In this case the `ListenAuto` method would change to :

```
async Task ListenAuto(IPAddress address,int port,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    try
        {        
            using var client=new TcpClient(endpoint);
            await client.ConnedtAsync(address,port,token);

            using var nwStream = client.GetStream();
            using var reader=new StreamReader(nwStream,Encoding.ASCII);

            var chars = new char[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            while (client.Connected && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                int charsRead = await reader.ReadAsync(chars, 0,chars.Length,token);  
                
                for(int i=0;i<charsRead;i++)
                {
                    _block.PostAsync(chars[i]);
                } 
            }
         }
         catch(OperationCanceledException)
         {
             //Cancelled, no need to show anything
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
         }     
}
```

Once an `ActionBlock` is created it will keep processing messages. When we want to stop it, we call `Complete()` and await for all pending messages to get processed through the `Completion` task:

```
public async void StopProcessing_Click()
{
    _manualCancel?.Cancel();
    _autoCancel?.Cancel();

    _block.Complete();
    await _block.Completion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Auto method should be executed on a separate thread so that a loop can interrupt the separate thread whenever you want.

For simplicity, you should probably use a CancellationToken and use the [`ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=net-5.0).

So in each event you can use the [`RunWorkAsync(object o)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerAsync_System_Object_) with an object being a CancellationToken.

You can probably test this with this sample console program:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var autoctsource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var autoct = autoctsource.Token;

            var manualctsource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var manualct = manualctsource.Token;

            Task auto = null;
            Task manual = null;

            auto = new Task(async () =>
            {
                if (manual.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                {
                    manualctsource.Cancel();
                }

                var tcp = new TcpClient();
                while (tcp.Connected)
                {
                    var stream = tcp.GetStream();
                    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(bytesToRead.AsMemory(0, tcp.ReceiveBufferSize), autoct);
                    //TCP code
                }

            }, autoct);

            manual = new Task(() =>
            {
                if (auto.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                {
                    autoctsource.Cancel();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(auto.Status);
                
                while(!manualct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    //Manual code loop
                }
            }, manualct);

            auto.Start();
            Task.Delay(5000);
            manual.Start();

        }
    }
```

Comment: The description is misleading (you're not running things on a separate thread, and you're certainly not interrupting another thread - which would be a horrible idea anyway), but you're close to a decent solution. Using `new Task` is a bad idea - either do `Task.Run`, or just call an async method _without_ await and store the returned task. `Read` returns zero when the connection is closed, don't check `Connected`. CancellationTokens aren't useful for start-stop like this - you can only switch once. Relying on task status also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use cold tasks just to manually start them afterwards. Tasks aren't threads. Calling `Task.Start` won't start execution, it will submit the job to the TaskScheduler for execution by a threadpool thread.

Comment: All your comments are clearly useful. This was just an example, not a complete solution and there are clearly some issues. I would personally inspire from [Two-way signaling](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent) to achieve what is requested. But this is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `NetworkStream.ReadTimeout` property with some value (for example, 5000 ms / 5 sec). If there wouldn't be response from server for 5 sec - handle timeout exception and go to a new loop iteration. Then again and again. Each 5 seconds loop will check, was BackgroundWorker cancelled or not and if was - loop would be breaked. You may configure timeout value, but remember, that `NetworkStream.Read` will wait for that time before new iteration, which would check BGW cancellation.

Something like that:

```
private TcpClient client;

private void ButtonRunWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker_Auto.IsBusy)
        backgroundWorker_Auto.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BackgroundWorker_Auto_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient(yourServerIP, yourServerPort);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // If failed to connect or smth...
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        // If client failed to initialize - no sense to continue, so close it and return.
        client?.Close();
        client?.Dispose();
        return;
    }

    using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
    {
        // Set time interval to wait for server response
        ns.ReadTimeout = 5000;

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            // If BackgroundWorker was cancelled - break loop
            if (backgroundWorker_Auto.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            // Wrap read attempt into try
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    // Code still waits here, but now only for 5 sec
                    bytesRead = ns.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle timeout exception (but not with MessageBox). Maybe with some logger.
                }
            } while (ns.DataAvailable); // Read while data from server available

            // Process response
            string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            switch (responseData)
            {
                case "1":
                    //Do something;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    //Do some other thing;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Close TCP Client properly
    client?.Close();
    client?.Dispose();
}

private void ButtonStopWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel BackgroundWorker
    backgroundWorker_Auto.CancelAsync();
}
```

**EDIT.** I do not recommend to use `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` here, because once you begin `await` it - `RunWorkerCompleted` fires with BackgroundWorker completion. `ReadAsync` probably usable, if run `TcpClient` with `Task.Run` and `CancellationToken`s.

Comment: `I do not recommend to use NetworkStream.ReadAsync` why? The real problem is using the obsolete BGW. All this code can be replace *and* simplified by using a single asynchronous method that does what `DoWork` does, using async methods instead. It's quite possible that `Task.Run` won't be needed at all

Comment: Agree. `Task`s is much simpler and usable for this kind of purposes. But because of using BGW by OP - i do not recommend put `async-await` on `DoWork`. If you want use `async-await` - use `Task`s, not BGW.

Comment: So don't post an answer with a BGW. That's the real problem. In any case `DoWork` is an event so you *can* use `async void` and `await` to avoid wasting a thread, even if it's a background thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you share an example?

Comment: You need example of `TcpClient` in `Task` instead of BGW?

Answer (score 0):

Check for DataAvailable prior to reading the NetworkStream, so it won't block the thread when there is nothing to read.

```
if(nwStream.CanRead && nwStream.DataAvailable)
{    
    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    ...
```

Comment: Good tip!! I was able to achieve what i intended with some modifications